# Multiple has_many relationships with same model through two different models, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

**I have a model in my rails app:**

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :sites
  has_many :users, through: :suppliers
end
```

Obviously this code won't work as the second line will just override the first, but I'm illustrating what I'm trying to achieve.

**The other classes:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sites, -> { uniq }
end

class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :images
end
```

**A user should own images that they've uploaded through sites and suppliers that they own.**

Is there another way of writing this or do I need to reconfigure the existing set up. Any help appreciated, let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Just wondering out loud.... why doesn't it work ? Off the top of my head it would seem that it works without modification.

Comment: It is working fine, please see image nested attribute again

Comment: Users can upload images through sites but they don't own them, so they can't edit/delete them. I think the second has_many in the images model overwrites the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... (By using polymorphic association you can DRY it)

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sites
  has_and_belongs_to_many :suppliers

  has_many :site_users, through: :sites
  has_many :supplier_users, through: :suppliers
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sites, -> { uniq }
  has_and_belongs_to_many :suppliers
end

class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :images
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :images
end
```

Comment: I also added the following into the image model: has_many :site_users, through: :sites, source: :users; has_many :supplier_users, through: :suppliers, source: :users

Answer (score 1):

Though I'm not quite sure about the relationship between your various objects, I think I'd solve this in the following manner:

```
class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sites
  has_and_belongs_to_many :suppliers

  has_many :site_images, through: :sites
  has_many :supplier_images, through: :suppliers
end

class Site
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :images, as: :imageable
end

class Supplier
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :images, as: :imageable
end

class Image
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Then you should be able to access the user's images by accessing `@user.site_images` and `@user.supplier_images`.